# Mixed Integer Programming with Large number of constraints

Tags: distributed-computing, linear-programming, or-tools, pulp, mixed-integer-programming

I have a lot of constraints(in millions) and want to solve a mixed integer problem. Tried using PuLP and OR-Tools(with SCIP solver), but they failed to solve the problem. I tried using DuaLip for parallel/distributed computing using spark, but it doesn't seem to have good documentation for usage. How should I proceed further?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there do not exist continuous LP solvers that do distributed computing. That would require some decomposition scheme. As LPs solve very fast we don't use those techniques anymore. An LP with a few million constraints is not very large these days. Quite often interior-point algorithms do quite well on these large problems (relative to Simplex algorithms). We solve LPs of this size on a completely routine basis on fairly standard hardware.

Your PuLP problem is likely more related to PuLP having problems generating the problem than the solver solving it. (Note that PuLP is not a solver). Python based modeling tools may be slower in generating easy LPs than the solver needs to solve it.

Note: the situation for MIP solvers is very different.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try to solve it with a general library without distributed computing and other than PuLP. My problem is of MIP type, can you recommend some good libraries to try?
Edit: prefarably Java/Python/Scala supported

Comment: MIP  ≠ LP. My answer is not very relevant for MIP solvers. The best MIP solvers (including allowing distributed computing) are all expensive commercial solvers.

Comment: I'm more sceptical about `An LP with a few million constraints is not very large these days.`. Variables okay, but Constraints hurt. In Mittelmanns LP [benchmarks](http://plato.asu.edu/ftp/lpsimp.html), only 2/40 have > 1million constraints and some  commercial solvers struggle (= timeout). Distributed computing as black-box solution to scalability issues (in MILPs) is probably also optimistic. In this regard also just the following remark: `Distributed parallel optimization of mixed integer programming (MIP) models has been deprecated in CPLEX 20.1.0 and will be removed in a future release.`